# CSS transition in Firefox bug

Tags: firefox, scale, css-transitions, transition

I have a problem with moz-transition in Firefox for images:

```
.view-tenth img {
   -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
   -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
   -o-transform: scaleY(1);
   -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
   transform: scaleY(1);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0s;
   -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0s;
   transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

When page loads all images start almost invisible (the opacity looks like about 0.1 or 0.3) and then fade to opacity about 0.8, and never 1.0. One or two images may load at once, bit other... It happens only with first page load. When I go to another page and then back to previous all images load well. I think this bug comes with some cashing synchronization.

I also use the "preload" script for images, but when I turn off this script the issue is still here.

I've notices that the problem disappears when I set transition duration 2s, but it's not a good decision, of coarse.

How can I fix this issue?

Added:

```
.view-tenth:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: scale(2);
   -moz-transform: scale(2);
   -o-transform: scale(2);
   -ms-transform: scale(2);
   transform: scale(2);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=1);
   opacity: 1;
}
```

When mouse is hovering on image it scales image from 1 to 2 with displaying before hidden div also with scale. Maybe I don't need to call transition for **all** elements if I use only scale attribute? What I have to write:

```
-moz-transition: **scaleY** 0.7s ease-in-out 0s;
```

But it doesn't take any effect.

Comment: What FF version are you using? Also provide your fiddle code.

Comment: FF version is 21.0. I don't know how to use fiddler.

Comment: I am using the same.  It works fine.

Comment: The code I've taken from here: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/index10.html

Comment: Its working. Check if you have placed your jquery code and css correctly.

Comment: I guess the issue comes from masonry script which adds opacity style to image wrapper.

Comment: I've found the source of problem. Preload script uses "opacity" animation when images load with speed of 1000ms. When I set this option without animation  (from 0 to 1 instantly) everything works fine in this case. The issue is in fade effect which works wrong with css3 transition in Firefox. I'm forced to set hard switching for opacity change instead of smooth appearance when page load. It's silly.